# How to configure TYPO3 to output non-translated pages in default language in the menu

Tags: menu, localization, typo3, fallback, typo3-10.x

I have two languages:

```
0: English, example.com (default language)
1: German, example.com/de/
```

If i visit the german version of the website i want all non-translated pages to appear in English, but with a link to the **english page**.

If i only set `hidePagesIfNotTranslatedByDefault` to `false`, pages don't appear.

If i additionally set `fallbacks: '0'` in the site config for the language German, pages titles appear in english, but with a link to a **german version**, e.g. `example.com/de/my-page`.
But this page doesn't exist and shouldn't exist (even not with content fallback), as that would mean duplicate content.

The goal is to show an all non-translated pages in their default language, with a correct link.
Is there a way to do it?